# Generic jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wonder, if it is possible to create generic parametric jobs ready to copy where the only post copy action is to redefine its parameters.

**During my investigation I find out that:**

```
 - I can use parameters in svn path definition
 - I can define the flow of builds using *Build Flow Plugin*
```

> However I cannot force Jenkins to use parameters inside job names definition for promotion process. Is any way to achieve that?

Since I create sometimes branches from master I would like to copy the whole configuration of jobs but only one difference most times is that in the job name definition I replace master with branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Why it not possible to use a parameter as the branch name?

Then when you start to build the job, you can input the parameters based on the branch you want to build.

Or find some way to get the branch info and inject it.

For example, we have one common job, which will monitor maybe 20 projects, if any of those job was merged into git, our gerrit trigger plugin will start to work, and all of job name, and branch is got dynamically from parameters.

Hope this works for you.